# Blender: как отрезать полигоны в отдельный объект по ребрам?

Tags: blender

Как сделать это с выделенными полигонами знаю. Но если я обведу ребра и нажму P - создается просто контур или вроде того.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью <kbd>P</kbd> отделяются только те элементы, которые выделены. Если выделены только ребра, значит только они будут отделены.

Если вы хотите отделить регион внутри, то сначала его надо выделить. Есть функция для этого: Select -> Select loops -> Select Loop Inner-Region

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]